# Making Gradio look nicer, banner and watermark?

Tags: python, user-interface, streamlit, gradio

I have a Gradio dashboard I am using to demo a Python model. Since my manager wants me to demo it to some higher-ups he wants it to look nicer.

Is there a way to add a banner on the top? We have a company banner I can add, I just don't know how to make it span the entire top before everything else on the page.

Also, I don't know if there is a way to add a watermark to the page. I would love it if it were just subtly behind everything else. I tried using a picture for the background, but I think the watermark would look better.